# Regular expression to find email address pattern of <string><number><string>

Tags: regex

We have an application that we suspect is getting spam/clickfarm email addresses signing up. A lot of them follow the pattern:

- `firstName:number:lastName@example.com`

For example,

- `tommy8512shira@example.com`
- `tommy785young@example.com`
- `tommy3265schmitt@example.com`

#### RegEx

`/(\w+)(\d+)(\w+)/g` gets me close to what I want but also captures numbers at the end of the string

Comment: Like [`/(\w+?)(\d+)(\w+)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/JWviZZ/1)? What numbers are there at the end of the string?

Comment: That's closer, but still captures ones like `someguy5649866@example.com`

Comment: Then [`/([^\W\d]+)(\d+)([^\W\d]+)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/JWviZZ/2) should work.

Comment: You rock. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\w` shorthand character class also matches digits and letters. You may either replace it with `[a-zA-Z]` or subtract the digits using a reverse char class - `[^\W\d]`.

Use either

```
([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)([a-zA-Z]+)
```

(see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/JWviZZ/4)) or an anchored version:

```
^([^\W\d]+)(\d+)([^\W\d]+)
^
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/JWviZZ/3). The `^` will anchor the pattern at the start of the string.